# how to ensure the integrity of the data in store/database?

Tags: databases, mysql, storage

I was wondering how can i as a system developer ensure that systems virtual wallet are not tampered with? for example lets a assume that my application allows a user to deposit and widthdraw money, where the account balance is stored in a database. how do i make sure that the requsted amount of withdrawment is legit ?

a bad scenario would be, that someone somehow got access to my database and change their account balance. How do i ensure the integrity of the data in store?

As my application will be using mysql, then its really easy if someone gets access to my cpanel account or somehow access the mysql database, to alter my records and i will have no way to prove that it was altered.

Comment: You need to develop that into your application and database. Setting up correct access controls and ensuring that logging is working is a good start, after that it is down to your setup and with little to go on I can't be more specific. Good luck :)

Comment: might consider blockchain solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys, not sure what more information will be relevant, so please throw some questions and i will try to give more specs.
@dandavis, interesting ..  will look into it.